# Animate shifting highlight in list (with Jquery?)

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a list with an active row. When clicking on another row, I want that to be highlighted instead (see snippet). So far so good.

But I also want that shift to be animated. As in: actually move the highlight down or up on the screen.

I assume that this is possible by using a div for the highlight with "position: absolute":
Upon clicking on another row, I could calculate the difference in screen position and then shift the "top" attribute of the div accordingly. For the animation I would then use CSS's transition.

But is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('li').on('click', function(){
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
  });

});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Row 1</li>
  <li class="highlight">Row 2</li>
  <li>Row 3</li>
  <li>Row 4</li>
</ul>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp0ZD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. Added an extra absolute li which travels around when you click other li's.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('li').on('click', function(){
  thisHeight = $(this).position().top;
   $('.highlight').css('top', thisHeight);
  });

});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  position:absolute;
  height:18px;
  width:calc(100% - 40px);
  content:'';
  top:18px;
  left:40px;
  z-index:0;
  list-style:none;
  transition-duration:.3s;
}

ul {
position:relative;
}

li {
position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="highlight"></li>
  <li>Row 1</li>
  <li>Row 2</li>
  <li>Row 3</li>
  <li>Row 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Definitely more elegant with another <li> and position: relative

Answer (score 0):

If it's only to have a smooth transition between the highlighted state and normal state, you can use `transition` CSS property like this :

```
.highlight 
{
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

You can change the duration of the transition of course.

Comment: this isn't expected behaviour. OP wants: " actually move the highlight down or up on the screen"